# Schedule Oracle backup

Tags: oracle, backup

What is the correct and best approach for backing up oracle automatically?
Which one should be use for schadule backup:
- Using oracle jobs OR
- Using os tools like cron
Or any other way?

Are there any powerful scripts for implement backup strategy  ? ( something like  Ola Hallengren for SQL server)

Comment: Use Oracle's built-in RMAN tool. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmquick.htm#BRADV89346). The docs devote a whole chapter to [the topic of scheduling](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-1F8297CD-CFD9-4BD0-8014-78FA147175B9.htm#ADMQS0932)

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Enterprise Manager](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/enterprise-manager/overview/index.html) has a wizard that helps setting up recommended backup strategy. See the following white paper ([Oracle RMAN Backups: Pushing the "Easy" Button](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/oem/havewala-rman-grid-089150.html)) for details..